# How to fix "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com:443"

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm new to Protractor. After installation using "npm install -g protractor" , when I'm trying to run "webdriver-manager update" command, getting below error.

Error logs from command prompt -

C:\Users\USER##\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager update

[15:50:38] E/start - Selenium Standalone is not present. Install with webdriver-manager update --standalone

C:\Users\USER##\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager update --standalone
[15:50:54] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\USER##\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[15:50:54] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\USER##\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

[15:50:54] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users##\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

events.js:183

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com:443

```
at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)

at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

Comment: run `npm i webdriver-manager -g` and then try to run the update command `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: If your network behind proxy, please specify proxy as `webdriver-manager update --proxy=<your proxy>`

Comment: First I ran "npm i webdriver-manager -g" so its downloaded some packages, when I'm trying to execute "webdriver-manager update" its throwing same error again(error mentioned in question ) @Madhan

Comment: Most times this is a corporate proxy issue. If you cannot navigate to https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ from Chrome, then you'll need to get an exception for these hosts / possibly use the proxy flag